Commit added to my PR but can't pull it locally
A commit was added to my PR by a reviewer. How do I pull this locally? I keep getting an abort message because i made the changes manually.

What is the exact error message you get? and the exact command you run? :)

your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge, please commit your changes or stash

So commit them or stash them? What's the problem? You might need to resolve conflicts after pulling changes. If you want to reject your changes for all changed files, you can git checkout -- .. After that your locally made changes will be undone and then you will be able to pull remote changes.

You can fetch and restore a PR in a local separate branch with gh pr checkout, but make sure your current git status is clean first.
gh pr checkout 1234 -b testBranch
# without gh
git fetch origin pull/1234/head:testBranch
git switch testBranch

Then you can reset your HEAD to a previous commit (one before the PR: source this answer), and you will be able to check in your IDE all the changes brought by the PR or, in your case, by that last commit
git reset --soft @~


If you want to keep your local changes/commits
git pull --rebase --autostash

which will

stash any uncommitted changes,
rebase your unpushed commits on top of the commits received from the remote, and
unstash your uncommitted changes.

You will have the opportunity to resolve conflicts along the way. This is the simplest and correct way to incorporate remote changes into your local work.

If you don't want to keep your local changes/commits
git fetch && git reset --hard origin/branchname

which will reset your local branch to the remote ref.
